# Weird behaviour of NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
NMinimize[{(Moment[TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 
   1] - 1.2974425414)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 2] - 
  1.9663181093401837715)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 3] - 
  3.524997729877075615786845)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 4] - 
  7.57620501366321245281015684)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 5] - 
  19.8019741854570677377555)^2, l1 > 0, l2 > 0, s1 > 0, s2 > 0}, {l1, l2, mu, s1, s2}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Gives the following minimum: 0.372412

But If I restrict `l1` to be greater than 5, then it gives a "better" minimum: 0.00185.

```
NMinimize[{(Moment[TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 
   1] - 1.2974425414)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 2] - 
  1.9663181093401837715)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 3] - 
  3.524997729877075615786845)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 4] - 
  7.57620501366321245281015684)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 5] - 
  19.8019741854570677377555)^2, l1 > 5, l2 > 0, s1 > 0,  s2 > 0}, {l1, l2, mu, s1, s2}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

How to avoid such behaviour? Maybe `FindFit` is better?

Thank you.

Comment: From the documentation, "If  f  and  cons  are  linear  or  convex, the  result  given  by  NMinimize  will  be  the  global  minimum, over  both  real  and  integer  values; otherwise, the  result  may  sometimes  only  be  a  local  minimum ." Also, use of machine precision in complicated calculations can be troublesome.

Comment: If you have access to raw data rather than the moments, look at [`FindDistributionParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon , is it possible to specify initial guess?

Comment: You cannot specify initial guesses with `NMinimize`; however, you can restrict the search to a domain (i.e., tighten the constraints). Alternatively, use the option `Method` to see if that helps.

Comment: @BobHanlon The four standard methods of `NMinimize` allow the specification of initial points. Search the doc http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html for `"InitialPoints"`.

Comment: @Goofy - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Metod->"RandomSearch"` option helps:

```
NMinimize[{(Moment[TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 
   1] - 1.2974425414)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 2] - 
  1.9663181093401837715)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 3] - 
  3.524997729877075615786845)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 4] - 
  7.57620501366321245281015684)^2 + (Moment[
   TukeyLambdaDistribution[{l1, l2}, mu, {s1, s2}], 5] - 
  19.8019741854570677377555)^2, l1 > 0, l2 > 0, s1 > 0, 
  s2 > 0}, {l1, l2, mu, s1, s2}, MaxIterations -> 1000,  Method -> "RandomSearch"]
```

> `{0.00177165, {l1 -> 3.64824, l2 -> 0.00844903, mu -> 0.775581,  s1 -> 0.0029117, s2 -> 0.527885}}`

and several warnings.